# Graph does not accept Property Options

Tags: graphs-and-networks

My question is concerned with the `Graph` functionality, which was newly implemented in Mathematica 8.  I already used `GraphPlot` and `LayeredGraphPlot` in the previous versions and in principle appreciate the new capabilities.  However, I still wonder if the current implementation is complete.  E.g. in the code below, I try to use `VertexCoordinates` for each vertex, which according to the documentation for `Graph`, should work.

```
vertices1 = {
   Property[1, {VertexCoordinates -> {0, 3}, VertexSize -> 0.3}],
   Property[2, VertexCoordinates -> {1, 2}],
   Property[3, VertexCoordinates -> {3, 3}]
 };

Graph[vertices1, {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3},  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDrawing", "LayeredLeft"}]
```

Other Options within `Property`, e.g. `VertexSize`, work correctly.  `VertexCoordinates` has no effect whatsoever.  `VertexCoordinates` will work as an option for `Graph`, but not as a `Property` for a particular vertex.

My other concern relates to `GraphLayout` and in particular to the Suboption `"PackingLayout"`, which also seems to have no influence whatsoever.  E.g. if I use `"LayeredDrawing"`, the Suboptions `"LayeredLeft"` or `"LayeredTop"` create the same `Graph`.

What is your experience?

Comment: I don't know why `Property` doesn't work here.  As far as I understand the docs, it should.  As you noticed, one workaround is using `VertexCoordinates` as an option to `Graph`.  Another one is setting vertex coordinates *after* the graph has been built.

Comment: Regarding "PackingLayout": as I understand, it is relevant only if the graph is not connected (i.e. it has several connected components).  The components will be laid out separately, then the "PackingOption" method will be used to lay out the separate components on the canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
ClearAll[g];
vertices1 = {1, 2, 3};
g = Graph[vertices1, {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}];
PropertyValue[{g, 1}, VertexSize] = .3;
PropertyValue[{g, 1}, VertexCoordinates] = {0, 3}; 
PropertyValue[{g, 2}, VertexCoordinates] = {1, 2};
PropertyValue[{g, 3}, VertexCoordinates] = {3, 3};
g
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
 vertices1 = {Property[1, {VertexSize -> 0.3}], 2, 3};
 coordlist = {{0, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}};
 g1 = Graph[vertices1, {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, 
    GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDrawing", "LayeredLeft"}];
 Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> coordlist[[VertexIndex[#1, #2]]]] &, g1, VertexList[g1]]
```

gives

[image]