# Organise a graph's vertices into levels

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to organise a graph's vertices in levels. Consider

```
g = {
  0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 0 -> 4, 0 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 8 -> 3, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 9, 
  6 -> 9, 6 -> 10, 7 -> 10, 8 -> 10, 9 -> 11, 9 -> 12, 10 -> 11, 10 -> 12 };
Graph[g]
```

Using nested list of vertices such as `{{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}`, I would like to see graph with 4 levels wherein vertices 0, 1, 2, 3 placed in line on the top level, vertices 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 in line on the level below and so on.

[image]

Comment: Which nodes would connect to which?

Comment: If you were to add a diagram showing the result you are seeking, it would help clarify your question. As it is, I am unable conceive how you would like to see the output from `Graph` to look.

Comment: nodes connection described in graph g and levels in nested list

Comment: So you want to describe the vertex coordinates by the second list? Have a look at [VertexCoordinates](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexCoordinates.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `VertexCoordinates` property

```
g = {0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 0 -> 4, 0 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 8 -> 3, 
   4 -> 9, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 9, 6 -> 10, 7 -> 10, 8 -> 10, 9 -> 11, 
   9 -> 12, 10 -> 11, 10 -> 12};

levels = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}};

graph = Graph[g, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Large];
```

Set vertex coordinates according to positions of vertices in `levels`:

```
graph2 = Fold[
  SetProperty[{#1, #2[[1]]}, VertexCoordinates -> #2[[2]]] &, graph, 
  Join @@ MapIndexed[Rule[#1, {#2[[2]] - Length[levels[[#2[[1]]]]]/2, -#2[[1]]}] &, 
   levels, {2}]]
```

[image]

See also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4536/4678).

**Update**

Inspired by the answer of István Zachar:

```
Graph[g, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Large, 
  VertexCoordinates -> ({#2, -#1} & @@@ 
    GraphEmbedding[Graph[g], {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {4, 5, 2, 2}}])]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! István Zachar's solution do not fit me because I use Mathematica 8.0

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков If you need a solution for Mathematica 8, please mention this in the question.

Answer (score 11):

In *Mathematica* 9+ one can use `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` with appropriate partitioning:

```
g = {0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 0 -> 4, 0 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 8 -> 3, 
   4 -> 9, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 9, 6 -> 10, 7 -> 10, 8 -> 10, 9 -> 11, 
   9 -> 12, 10 -> 11, 10 -> 12};

Graph[g, GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {4, 5, 2, 2}},
   VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the embedding assumes (and partitions) the vertex list as it would be returned by `VertexList[Graph[g]]` so if you shuffle the edges, the vertex layout will be messed up.

Unfortunately, `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` does not accept the common method option `"Orientation" -> Top`, so one has to fall back to more primitive rotations:

```
Rotate[Graph[g, GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding",
    "VertexPartition" -> {4, 5, 2, 2}},
  VertexLabels -> (# -> Rotate[#, Pi/2] & /@ Range[0, 12])], -Pi/2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]